# VBA code to loop through recordset and copy fields

Tags: forms, vba, clipboard

I have a database where people can copy data from a form to the clipboard, using the following code:

```
Private Sub cmdCopy_Click()
Dim strToCopy As String
    strToCopy = Forename & " " & Surname & vbCrLf & vbCrLf & "Intended Course: " & [Intended course] & vbCrLf & vbCrLf & "Subject: " & [Subject] & vbCrLf & vbCrLf & "Predicted Grade: " & [Predicted Grade] & vbCrLf & vbCrLf & "Academic skills: " & [Academic skills] & vbCrLf & vbCrLf & "Suitablity for intended course: " & [Suitability] & vbCrLf & vbCrLf & " Work ethic: " & [Work Ethic] & " " & vbCrLf & vbCrLf & "Prior attainment: " & " " & [Prior attainment] & " " & vbCrLf
    'open a dummy form and write the string to it
    DoCmd.OpenForm "frmDummy"
    Screen.ActiveForm.txtCopy = strToCopy
    Screen.ActiveForm.txtCopy.SetFocus
    'copy from form to clipboard
    DoCmd.RunCommand acCmdCopy
    'close the form
    DoCmd.Close
End Sub
```

However, the user then has to press "next record" and repeat the process several times over. I'm after a way of looping through and copying the data off the form until the end of the dataset is reached. I tried this:

```
 Private Sub cmdCopy_Click()
Dim strToCopy As String
While Me.CurrentRecord < Me.Recordset.RecordCount-1
    strToCopy = Forename & " " & Surname & vbCrLf & vbCrLf & "Intended Course: " & [Intended course] & vbCrLf & vbCrLf & "Subject: " & [Subject] & vbCrLf & vbCrLf & "Predicted Grade: " & [Predicted Grade] & vbCrLf & vbCrLf & "Academic skills: " & [Academic skills] & vbCrLf & vbCrLf & "Suitablity for intended course: " & [Suitability] & vbCrLf & vbCrLf & " Work ethic: " & [Work Ethic] & " " & vbCrLf & vbCrLf & "Prior attainment: " & " " & [Prior attainment] & " " & vbCrLf
    DoCmd.OpenForm "frmDummy"
    Screen.ActiveForm.txtCopy = Screen.ActiveForm.txtCopy + strToCopy
    Screen.ActiveForm.txtCopy.SetFocus
    DoCmd.GoToRecord Record:=acNext
Wend
    DoCmd.RunCommand acCmdCopy
    DoCmd.Close
End Sub
```

However, this throws an error saying the copy command is unavailable here. I suspect (but not sure) that the .SetFocus command has to immediately precede the acCmdCopy command and that this is why it isn't working... Am I correct, and if so, any ideas how I could get around this?

Thanks very much in advance!

EDIT: Based on feedback from below, so far I have this code, but it's not copying anything to the clipboard...

```
Dim strToCopy As String
While Me.CurrentRecord < Me.Recordset.RecordCount - 1
    strToCopy = Forename & " " & Surname & vbCrLf & vbCrLf & "Intended Course: " & [Intended course] & vbCrLf & vbCrLf & "Subject: " & [Subject] & vbCrLf & vbCrLf & "Predicted Grade: " & [Predicted Grade] & vbCrLf & vbCrLf & "Academic skills: " & [Academic skills] & vbCrLf & vbCrLf & "Suitablity for intended course: " & [Suitability] & vbCrLf & vbCrLf & " Work ethic: " & [Work Ethic] & " " & vbCrLf & vbCrLf & "Prior attainment: " & " " & [Prior attainment] & " " & vbCrLf
Wend

With New DataObject
        .SetText s
        .PutInClipboard
End With
```

CHANGED IT AGAIN bringing back the dummy form since .SetText can't take named arguments. Now get error message "object required"

```
Dim strToCopy As String
While Me.CurrentRecord < Me.Recordset.RecordCount - 1
    strToCopy = Forename & " " & Surname & vbCrLf & vbCrLf & "Intended Course: " & [Intended course] & vbCrLf & vbCrLf & "Subject: " & [Subject] & vbCrLf & vbCrLf & "Predicted Grade: " & [Predicted Grade] & vbCrLf & vbCrLf & "Academic skills: " & [Academic skills] & vbCrLf & vbCrLf & "Suitablity for intended course: " & [Suitability] & vbCrLf & vbCrLf & " Work ethic: " & [Work Ethic] & " " & vbCrLf & vbCrLf & "Prior attainment: " & " " & [Prior attainment] & " " & vbCrLf
    DoCmd.OpenForm "frmDummy"
    Screen.ActiveForm.txtCopy = Screen.ActiveForm.txtCopy + strToCopy
Wend

With New DataObject
        .SetText frmDummy.txtCopy
        .PutInClipboard
End With
```

Comment: I think that `Named Argument` is a red herring! http://www.mrexcel.com/forum/excel-questions/800285-error-dataobj-settext-text.html ... I'm going to update the code slightly ... lets have a peek to see what exactly is in strToCopy using MsgBox ... is it what you expect?

Comment: It's unclear to me what you are trying to do.  I would point out, however, that if you are visiting several records then you may need your string variable to declared OUTSIDE the click event.  So put `Dim strToCopy As String` at the top of the form module, right under `Option Explicit`.  (You DO have `Option Explicit`, I trust?)

Comment: Does "form" mean a form in MS Access?  I feel there should be another tag.

Comment: You can have forms in Excel too :0)

Comment: Also, a local string variable should be fine in this instance as it is built in one go inside the function, and not referenced outside of the function.

Comment: @smandoli - as per my comment above, I don't know VBA at all, so I have no idea about option explicit! 
I wasn't allowed to add the tag "access" when I created the post

Comment: Moving the variable declaration outside of the method has got it working without an error but unfortunately it only copies what is on the last record, and not the ones that precede it! Will keep bashing away...

Comment: GOT THERE! Thanks anyway :)

Answer (score 0):

Try this ...

```
Private Sub cmdCopy_Click()
    Dim strToCopy As String

    While Me.CurrentRecord < Me.Recordset.RecordCount - 1
        strToCopy = strToCopy & Forename & " " & Surname & vbCrLf & vbCrLf & "Intended Course: " & [Intended course] & vbCrLf & vbCrLf & "Subject: " & [Subject] & vbCrLf & vbCrLf & "Predicted Grade: " & [Predicted Grade] & vbCrLf & vbCrLf & "Academic skills: " & [Academic skills] & vbCrLf & vbCrLf & "Suitablity for intended course: " & [Suitability] & vbCrLf & vbCrLf & " Work ethic: " & [Work Ethic] & " " & vbCrLf & vbCrLf & "Prior attainment: " & " " & [Prior attainment] & " " & vbCrLf
    Wend

    Msgbox(strToCopy)

    With New DataObject
        .SetText strToCopy
        .PutInClipboard
    End With

    'the text should now be in the clipboard!
End Sub
```

---

There are probably better ways to do this using a macro that creates the string without using the form (eg click a macro button and it all ends up in the clipboard - no form required)!

For instance ...

```
Sub Test()

    Dim s As String

    For i = 1 To 5

        s = s & Cells(i, 1).Value

    Next i

    With New DataObject
        .SetText s
        .PutInClipboard
    End With

    Range("B1").PasteSpecial

End Sub
```

when used on this sheet yields the result in cell B1 ... this could be adapted to loop through records, rather than cells ...

[image]

Comment: Unfortunately that still gives the same error message so that's clearly not the problem. Thanks though!

Comment: I'm just hacking around with code that was created by a colleague so it may not be the most efficient way... Trouble is I don't know VBA very well/at all so just applying my general programming knowledge, but finding it tricky. If anyone can give me any code to get this working I'd really appreciate it.

Comment: I've updated my answer to reflect the different approach ... after you click the button hooked up to `cmdCopy_Click` the data should magically appear in the clipboard ready for pasting :0)

Comment: Thanks... I'm trying something similar but the line 
With New DataObject throws an error "user-defined type not defined"

Comment: Did you miss something off the end of that comment by accident or do you just like keeping people in suspense? :0p

Comment: No it was a complete comment... What am I keeping you in suspense about?!

Comment: Ok. That's an easy fix ... you need to add a reference to `Microsoft Forms 2.0 Object Library` ... you can do it manually by following these instructions http://excel-macro.tutorialhorizon.com/vba-excel-reference-libraries-in-excel-workbook/, or the quickest way is to just add a new form to the project and it should add the reference for you

Comment: Lol. Must has been a problem on my browser ... i could only see up to ' With New DataObject ' :0) Your full comment makes a lot more sense!

Comment: Unfortunately when I go to "tools", "references" is greyed out!

Comment: That might be because you are in 'break mode' try selecting Run>Reset from the menu

Comment: Yes, you were right about that one! However, there is no library with the name you give above

Comment: There is an even more manual(!) way ... Some­times you won’t find the desired ref­er­ences in the list, say you won’t find “Microsoft Forms 2.0 Object Library” in the tool/reference list in that case you need to browse the FM20.DLL file from the C:\windows\system32 folder.

Comment: Thanks, found it and now not getting that error message. I can click the button with no error message, however the required text isn't copied to clipboard. I'll update my OP with the new code

Comment: Can you edit your original question and add the code to the bottom please :0)

Comment: Yes. I believe that's my fault ... the line `.SetText s` is putting the variable `s` onto the cliboard. The only problem with that is the variable with the data is actually called `strToCopy`! ... so that line should read `.SetText strToCopy`

Comment: See, that's what I first assumed so I did have that to start with, but that gave me an error about passing an invalid argument!

Comment: Is it working now? That looks right to me ... it certainly seems to work on the second example i gave :0)

Comment: No, I still get the invalid argument error - not sure why! :(

Comment: Ah, I've Googled it and SetText doesn't support named arguments: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa244176(v=vs.60).aspx

Comment: Edited the above post again with the next thing I've tried!